# page not showing in different template

Tags: magento-1.8, template

I have installed magebuzz shopping list extension. when I click on the link to add a product to a shopping list in the default theme I go to a page which looks like this (and is correct)

[image: correct page]

but if I change the theme to a purchased theme I have this empty page:

[image: incorrect page]

any idea where the error could be or how I could figure out what the problem is?

Answer (score 3):

It means the template and skin files are probably in the wrong directory.
Add the template files to the `app/design/frontend/base/default/...` and the skin files to `skin/frontend/base/default/...`.

Now the styling for the extension should be available for all themes

Comment: i guess you misunderstood my question. the problem is not that in screenshot 1 there is no styling, the problem is that in screenshot 2 i don't have the content like in screenshot 1

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that i missed a xml file in frontend/mytheme/default/layout. After adding the xml file of the extension, it worked fine :), thx for help

Comment: Thats what I said, add the template files (phtml and layout xml) to your `base/default` so they are available in all themes

Comment: my theme was in another package, so in the base default would not help, but now i understand your answer, it was partially right, thanks for the help !